# What's the tidiest way to get hierarchy from csv to a database?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, hierarchical-data

In a web app my users upload a csv file and I need to check it on the way into the database. Part of the information forms a simple hierarchical dataset, so I want to make sure that rows are unique. Here's what I was thinking of doing, with an example.

CSV includes these rows...

```
field5      field6      field7
fred        bert        apple
fred        bert        apple
fred        george
fred        george      pear
will        tom         orange
will        tom         plum
```

I was going to absorb them into a PHP array like this.

```
$unique_fields = array();
while( $row = fgetcsv($handle) ){
    if( $row[5] ){
        if( !array_key_exists( $row[5] , $unique_fields ) ){
            $unique_fields[ $row[5] ] = array();
        }
        if( $row[6] ){
            if( !array_key_exists( $row[6] , $unique_fields[ $row[5] ] )){
                $unique_fields[ $row[5] ][ $row[6] ] = array();
            }

            if( $row[7] ){
                if( !array_key_exists( $row[7], $unique_fields[ $row[5] ][ $row[6] ]  )){
                    $unique_fields[ $row[5] ][ $row[6] ][ $row[7] ] = array();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this is a good idea (and I'm open to suggestions) - what's the best way after that? I want to transfer the array into my database so that it looks like the csv example above, but without duplicates.

Comment: How the hierarchical structure is involved in this problem? Do you only need to dedupe rows?

Comment: @Skrol29 - the point is to simplify the hierarchy from the csv. The csv might have 10,000 lines, but the hierarchy in the relevant columns might only contain (say) 10-12 unique items. These will go into a different table from the rest of the csv data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, no one wanted a stab at it, so I persevered and this is what I came up with. I'll watch the page in case someone has a better solution. Thanks for looking.

```
if( count($unique_fields) ){
    foreach( $unique_fields as $k1=>$v1 ){
        if( is_array($v1) ){
            foreach( $v1 as $k2=>$v2 ){
                if( is_array($v2) ){
                    foreach( $v2 as $k3=>$v3 ){
                        //insert $k1, $k2, $k3
                    }
                }else{
                    //insert $k1, $k2
                }
            }
        }else{
            //insert $k1 on its own
        }
    }
}
```